# Get URL response's console log in Webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview

I used [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin to show Webview in a flutter. Currently, I open stripe API in Webview. After stripe API success it will redirect to my server API. In this API, validate stripe cards and send a response that prints in the console. I am not getting this console log on the flutter side.

```
                       WebView(
                            initialUrl: "https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&scope=read_write&redirect_uri=${baseUrl}/transaction/connect&state=161",
                            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                            javascriptChannels:  [
                              JavascriptChannel(
                                  name: 'Print',
                                  onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
                                    print('Message: ${message.message}');
                                  }),
                            ].toSet(),
                            onPageStarted: (url) {
                              debugPrint("onPageStarted $url");
                            },
                            onPageFinished: (url) {
                              debugPrint("onPageFinished $url");
                            })
```

I have tried to get Javascript response from API in JavascriptChannel and this gets in android but not getting at the iOS side.

1) Is there any way to get these logs on the flutter side?

2) Is there any alternative to get a response from by API to review in flutter?

Comment: You can also try my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews. For your use case, you can simply listen to the `onConsoleMessage` event!

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative to get a call back from Stripe API. In response to API callback, I had redirect to another back end API.

```
 public connectWithStripe = async (req: CustomRequest, res: Response) => {
    request.post(process.env.StripeConnecturl
        , {
            form: {
                client_secret: process.env.StripeKey,
                code: req.query.code,
                grant_type: "authorization_code",
            },
        }, async (error: any, response: any) => {
            if (response && response.statusCode === 200) {
                const stripeDetails = {
                    stripeAccountId: JSON.parse(response.body).stripe_user_id,
                };
                return res.redirect('connect-success');  // redirect when successfully stripe account 
            } else {
                return res.redirect('connect-fail');   // fail
            }
        });
}
```

At flutter side, we get URL change in navigationDelegate function.

```
WebView(
    initialUrl: url,
    navigationDelegate: (request) {
      if (request.url.contains('connect-success')) {
        // TODO when api success
      } else if (request.url.contains('connect-fail')) {
        // TODO when api fail
      }
      return NavigationDecision.navigate;
    },
)
```